# Add fix amount to all orders as packaging price

Tags: commerce

I want to add  a fix amount to all orders as packaging price in commerce,I think first I need custom line item and named it as packaging price, then add that to orders with rules or in custom module, but this is just a idea.
 **Anybody know how can I add a fix amount to all orders as packaging price** (I also have discount in our commerce system and used it) **?**

Comment: To clarify, for every order you want a fixed packaging price.  Will this packaging price ever change?  Will every packaging price be the same, no matter if there is 1 product in your order, or 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check this module [commerce fees](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees) maybe help you

Comment: This is not complete what I want, but it help me to achieve my job

Comment: our target is to achieve your job,, so it nice to know you did it